# Could not find RubyGem rails - Rails Server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I'm new to rails/ruby and I'm following a tutorial on how to create your first app using git and heroku!

After figuring out the sqlite3 debacle, the error I receive now comes every time I try to start a server.

```
rails server
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:827:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:261:in `activate'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:68:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

This error is a pain in the arse, and I don't know how to get around it. There's several articles on here about this particular error, but no one mentions receiving this error while trying to launch the server.

Is there anybody out there that could walk me through the steps to take to remedy this.

- Should I provide my gemfile
- Should I also provide my database.yml file for reviewing
- Logs, anything else I'm not mentioning that could be of help to figure out the source of this problem

Let me know, I'm trying to move forward ad don't want to be stuck at this particular error for days.

Answer (score 0):

First you should install rvm: https://rvm.io/rvm/install then you should install ruby =< 1.9.3

`rvm install 2.1`

then you should install rails

`rvm use 2.1 && gem install rails`

then

`cd PROJECT_PATH && rails server`

everything should work fine

Comment: I tried that, and I 'cd PROJECT_PATH & rails server' and got the same thing!

Comment: I thing, you should set new ruby:

`rvm use 2.1` before installation rails